# Synchron Task Cancellation

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I am looking for a way to do a synchronous task cancellation. I have a task like this:

```
public Task AddAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    Task result = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        // So wait forever
        var wait = new ManualResetEvent(false);
        var waitIndex = WaitHandle.WaitAny(new[] { wait,
            cancellationToken.WaitHandle});

        switch (waitIndex)
        {
            case 0:
                Debug.WriteLine("Everything fine");
                break;
            case 1:
                Debug.WriteLine("Cancelled");
                Thread.Sleep(5000);
                cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                break;
        }
        return;
    }, cancellationToken);

    return result;
}
```

And the asynchronous method will be called like this:

```
var ts = new CancellationTokenSource();
var t = AddAsync(ts.Token);
if (!t.Wait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)))
{
    ts.Cancel();
}
```

So after the timeout I call cancel but the task is taking some time to cancel. So how can I make a synchronous cancel call?

Comment: Cancelling is taking time because you are calling sleep. Or do I misunderstand the question?

Comment: If you want the main thread to wait until the task has finished shutting down, then wait on the task again. That is `ts.Cancel(); t.Wait();`

Comment: When will "wait" be signaled?

Comment: If you want to wait until the task is completed after cancelling the code from Jim should work fine: `ts.Cancel(); t.Wait();`. I believe the WaitHandle.WaitAny will be signalled almost immediately.

Comment: The `t.Wait()` should be signaled when the task finishes. In your example above, that would be when the exception is thrown. As MrZoidberg points out, the `WaitAny` is signaled immediately when you call `ts.Cancel`.

Comment: So I think the best solution would be to call t.Wait once more after the Cancel call as Jim mentioned above. Any other ideas?

Comment: @FranzGsell you haven't told us yet what you want to happen. So this question cannot be answered. Tell us.

Comment: So what I want to happen is, that after a task takes too long I want to abort that task and in addition I want to wait after the "abort" is completed and the task is finished.